# Can I install ubuntu without disturbing any files, without dual boot?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows

I have been googling for a while, and what I read says ubuntu deletes the files on the partition I install it.
I want to install it on the c drive, but i don't want to lose its current contents. Is there any way for me to install ubuntu without disturbing any other files (Or any files other than the windows files)?

Comment: Windows will use NTFS and by default, Ubuntu will want to create its own partitioning scheme... in order to do what you are suggesting, your only option may be Wubi http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer which will leave everything intact, but will limit you to 12.04 as I'm pretty sure it's no longer being developed. Another option, is to run Ubuntu in a VirtualBox virtual machine...

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of guides which answer your question, let me introduce you with one of them:

- [Full How-To](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu). It says, *you should not delete any files*, just reduce the Windows' partition size and install Ubuntu on vacated place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't suppress Windows and replace it with Ubuntu like that. Mainly because Ubuntu doesn't use NTFS, and the C:/Documents and Settings/Yourname/ means nothing to Ubuntu.

But, you can install Ubuntu without loosing your files with some manipulations (cheater, booo !). *Note that none of your windows software will work on Ubuntu as it.*

For example, I use Ubuntu on a 50Gb partition, and I also have a 700Gb NTFS partition for my documents.
The manipulation is quite simple but varies depending on your free space/an external storage disk:

**1) You have enough free space to duplicate all your files :**

- Install Ubuntu in dual-boot on a maximum-sized EXT4 partition (example, you have a 1Tb hard disk with 600Gb free, you install Ubuntu on a ~580Gb partition)
- Boot on Ubuntu
- Copy all your files from Windows into Ubuntu (example : My Documents, on C:/Documents and Settings/Yourname/My Documents can be moved to /home/yourname/documents).

  /!\ *Be sure to save ALL that you want, next step will completely erase your non-copied files*.
- Use OS-Uninstaller (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller`) to remove windows
- Boot with a Ubuntu livecd
- Use Gparted (from the livecd!) to delete the old windows partition (wich should be blank), and extend your Ubuntu partition.

**2)  You have an external support (usb hdd, another hard-disk connected to your motherboard, ...) :**

- Copy all your files from Windows into the external support

  /!\ *Be sure to save ALL that you want, next step will completely erase your non-copied files*.
- Install a brand new Ubuntu and erase all your windows files.
- Copy your files from the external support into Ubuntu (/home/yourname/Documents, /home/yourname/Images, etc. )

---

If you don't have enough free space to duplicate nor an external storage, you could try this, BUT it's really starting to get wierd :

- Install Ubuntu on a small EXT4 partition (like 8Gb)
- Remove your Windows files (C:/Program Files and C:/Windows)
- Always use the NTFS partition mounted (usually in /media/XXX)to play with your files, but you will have to deal with strange directories like */media/XXX/Documents \and \Settings/Yourname/My \Documents/* for your old "My Documents" directory.
- Delete the Windows entries from Grub or skip grub to always start on Ubuntu.

EDIT : this last solution is very similar to the one Danatela suggested while I was writing this.